# Is there a way to do this in bash? echo $$((2-1))

Tags: bash, shell

I have a few strings in $1 to $#. I want to perform a simple arithmetic expression and echo out the value of $ based on the # of the expression.

eg. set file1 file2 file3 file4

I want to echo $2 (file2) but using an arithmetic expression "echo $$((3-1))", which I thought would resolve to $2 but bash just throws an error.

Comment: Yeah, a bit enigmatic, those sentences.  Can you explain a bit more clearly?

Comment: Can you give example input and output so that we see exactly what you mean?

Comment: Maybe start by explaining what "the value of $" means and "the # of the expression".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use variable indirection:

```
set -- foo bar baz
var=$((1+1))
echo "${!var}"
```

This will print the value of `$2`, i.e. "bar".

Comment: +1 for recognizing what the question was asking for.  Impressive reading between the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Using the substring expansion operator:

```
$ set -- file1 file2 file3 file4
$ echo ${@:$((3-1)):1}
file2
```